# Transfer data from iOS app to Unity3D

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unity-game-engine

What is the proper way for transfering complex objects from iOS app to Unity3D using c plugin? For example, I have to transfer an `NSArray`, which contains Rewards. Each Reward contains `UIImage`, `NSString`-s, some `float` values, etc.

As I know, I can send only a single string to Unity3D. I found a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282454/any-proper-way-of-sending-byte-data-to-unity3d-from-a-c-plugin) with sending string with byte data and deconding it in Unity. Is it the right solution in my case?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided, that the best solution for data transfer is using JSON strings. In Unity I used tiny library litJSON for parsing.

When I had to transfer image, I saved it on device and transfered path to the image.